# How to add '§' in section heading?

Tags: formatting

I am curious of how to insert '§' in the section heading like the image below?
Thanks!

The following is the setup I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{ left=1.30in, right=1.30in, } 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{lmodern, enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Palatino}
```

[image]

Comment: Depends on what your setup is, so please provide a minimal example the resembles the setup you're using (documentclass and relevant packages)

Comment: The following is the setup I have:

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{
 left=1.30in,
 right=1.30in,
 }

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd} 
\usepackage{lmodern, enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont{Palatino}

Comment: Welcome! What daleif meant is that you should write [something like this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140456) in the body of your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reminder!

Comment: It would help if you could extend your code so we can compile it i.e. make a small example that ends with `\end{document}` so we can copy and paste it without having to build it ourselves :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is an option with `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ left=1.30in, right=1.30in }
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{lmodern, enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} this is not needed
\usepackage{fontspec}

%here is the code to format sections
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{5mm}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More information about the formatting could be found in the [documentation of the package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled with the `titlesec` package. This only adds the paragraph symbol to the `section`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\S\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
    \section{start}
    \subsection{next}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!